# Why does my deep array copy change it's value outside for loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, genetic-algorithm, deep-copy, mutation

I'm creating a Genetic Algorithm written in Java. The mutation function flips the bits in the array at an assigned probability.
The mutation function is not retaining the mutated population of arrays (Individuals).

```
public static void mutation(Individual[] population, Individual[] mutatedOffspring, double mutationRate) {

    // Iterate through gene, randomly select whether
    // or not to change the value of the genome
    //
    System.out.println("\nMUTATION\n");
    Random mutant = new Random();
    Individual[] offspring = new Individual[POPULATION_SIZE];

    System.out.println("mutated offspring array");
    for (int i = 0; i < (population.length); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < population[i].gene.length; j++) {
            // flip bits in array at preset probability (0.1)
            if (mutationRate > mutant.nextDouble()) {
                if (population[i].gene[j] == 0) {
                    population[i].gene[j] = 1;
                } else if (population[i].gene[j] == 1) {
                    population[i].gene[j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        // Deep copy contents of mutated array into new object array index (Individual)
        fitness(population);
        offspring[i] = new Individual(population[i].gene, population[i].fitness);
        // Print both mutated array and copied array to show successful copy
        System.out.println("offspring " + i + Arrays.toString(population[i].gene) + (population[i].fitness));
        System.out.println("copy:     " + i + Arrays.toString(offspring[i].gene) + (offspring[i].fitness));
    }
    //print same array outside loop of population
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < offspring.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("copy:     " + i + Arrays.toString(offspring[i].gene) + (offspring[i].fitness));
    }
    // deep copy outside p of population using .clone
    for (int i = 0; i < offspring.length; i++) {
        mutatedOffspring[i] = offspring[i].clone();
    }

    fitness(mutatedOffspring);
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("deep copied array using .clone() outside loop");

    for (int i = 0; i < mutatedOffspring.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("offspring " + i + Arrays.toString(mutatedOffspring[i].gene) + (mutatedOffspring[i].fitness));
    }
}
```

After the first iteration of the GA, the mutation function returns a population of Individuals, which are all copies of the **last** individual in the population, not of all the different 'mutated' individuals. (The fitness values at the end of the arrays haven't been evaluated).

**1st ITERATION**

copy within loop of population:

```
offspring 0[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]4
copy:     0[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]4
offspring 1[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]3
copy:     1[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]3
offspring 2[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]6
copy:     2[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]6
offspring 3[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]8
copy:     3[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]8
offspring 4[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
copy:     4[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
offspring 5[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]5
copy:     5[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]5
```

same copied array outside loop of population:

```
copy:     0[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]4
copy:     1[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]3
copy:     2[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]6
copy:     3[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]8
copy:     4[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
copy:     5[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]5
```

deep copy using .clone() outside loop

```
offspring 0[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]5
offspring 1[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]3
offspring 2[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
offspring 3[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
offspring 4[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]7
offspring 5[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]5
```

**2nd ITERATION**

copy within loop of population:

```
offspring 0[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]4
copy:     0[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]4
offspring 1[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]5
copy:     1[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]5
offspring 2[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]3
copy:     2[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]3
offspring 3[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]5
copy:     3[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]5
offspring 4[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
copy:     4[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 5[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
copy:     5[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
```

same copied arrays outside loop of population:

```
copy:     0[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
copy:     1[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]5
copy:     2[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]3
copy:     3[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]5
copy:     4[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
copy:     5[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
```

deep copy using .clone() outside loop

```
offspring 0[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 1[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 2[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 3[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 4[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
offspring 5[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]4
```

I'm sure I'm doing a deep copy by creating a new individual and assigning it the values of the Individual I wish to copy to it after each iteration.
I've also tried creating a clone() function in the Individual class.

```
public Individual clone(){
    Individual individual = new Individual(gene, fitness);
    individual.gene = gene;
    individual.fitness = fitness;
    return individual;
}
```

Both methods produce population of identical Individuals (or arrays) which are a copy of the last Individual in the mutated population whether used inside the loop or out.
In the example the last two arrays to copy are the same but I assure you the resulting offspring/ mutated offspring arrays are all a copy of the last one.

I want to retain a population of the mutated arrays for the GA to work.

Comment: I should note when I run this method 100 times on its own in a test it performs perfectly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. I think you are not correctly interpreting the GA fundamentals. Are you taking the whole population, and then "mutating" every single element of the array with 10% probability? 
If that is the case, you are mutation almost every single element of the population. That doesn't seem correct. You should apply this percentage to select ONLY a 10% of the population to participate in mutation every generation.

Besides that, I think your problem is that you are not making a hard-copy of the genome.

```
Individual individual = new Individual(gene, fitness);
individual.gene = gene;
```

When you do individual.gene = gene; you are actually pointing this new individual to the genome of the "parent". Is a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906861/needs-help-for-genetic-algorithm-single-point-crossover-mechanism-in-java/39922787#39922787) question.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, my clone wasn't doing each genome.
Also, yes I thought each individual in a population is a candidate for mutation in each generation? And yes I change the probability of mutation and each genome is potentially mutated? I'll read up on this, thanks again.